# How to print Buffred image as thumbnail in java?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, image-scaling, imagesource

Here i'm scaling image and saving in minImage (Buffred Image format)now how can i print that image as

```
BufferedImage minImage = ImageSale(buffered, minImageWidth, minImageHeight, TYPE_INT_RGB);

out.println("<img src=\""+minImage+"\">");
```

How to print image as thumb,please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have an issue with understanding the difference between a client and a server and what information they have available to each other, as well as the information that is maintained by HTML.

HTML is a plain text document, technically, it can't contain binary information (such as image data) and you really don't want to try and do this any way, as the HTML page itself should download relatively quickly.

The client HTML will need a reference to the image on the file server (or within the web servers context).  This is typically done by saving the file to the server in a location which is accessible by the browser.

If you don't want to save the images to disk, then you will need to create some kind of "memory cache" which contains the key to the image, so that when the browser requests the image from the server you can look it up from the cache and return a stream of the image to the client browser.

This would require you to seed the URL with some kind of identifier that could be mapped to the cache

Comment: This i'm printing in sevlet,is it possible?in minImage i have all information of new image such as height and widht but i dont know how to print that as image,can u guide me.

Comment: No, it's not printing in the servlet, the servlet is producing a HTML response from a browser/client request, which is shown in the browser.  Doesn't matter if the web server is running locally or not, this is not going to work, nor is it the way it should be done.  Either write the file to a local context (within the web server) and use that relative path as the img src or create another servlet whose sole responsibility to is to look at "image codes" from a, in memory, cache (which is going to be expensive) and write the image binary data through it's output stream...

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer,Is there any sample program to understand .please guide me.

Comment: That would depend on the Servlet API version and the Servlet container you are using, but you could try something like [this](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-download-file-example)